# Comparing numbers with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

How can I loop through an array of numbers and compare them to multiple sets of numbers. I am trying to program the game logic for a Tic Tac Toe project. When the players click a square the number of the square that was clicked is stored in p1Taken or p2Taken. I am trying to loop through those arrays and compare the numbers to the numbers for the squares needed to win. Only the first if statement works and I don’t think it’s bc of the number of squares but because there is 3 numbers in the array. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
const turnTaken = {
    X: [],
    O: []
}

var whosTurn = 'X';

let p1Taken = turnTaken.X; 
let p2Taken = turnTaken.O; 

const gameGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");
const message = document.getElementById("message");

for(i=0, l=gameGrid.length; i < l; i++){ 
    const boardNum = gameGrid[i].getAttribute("value");

    gameGrid[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) { 

        if(whosTurn == 'X') {
            message.innerHTML = "O's Turn";
            player1Turn(e);
        } else {
            message.innerHTML = "X's Turn";
            player2Turn(e);
        }
    });         
}


function player1Turn(e){
    const clickedValue = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    const clicked = e.target;

    const xIcon = document.createElement("IMG");
    const srcX = "img/x-icon.png";
    xIcon.setAttribute("src", srcX);

    clicked.appendChild(xIcon);
    p1Taken.push(clickedValue);
    whosTurn = 'O';  

    player1CheckWin(p1Taken);

}

function player2Turn(e){    
    const clickedValue = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    const clicked = e.target;

    const oIcon = document.createElement("IMG");
    const srcO = "img/o-icon.png";
    oIcon.setAttribute("src", srcO);

    clicked.appendChild(oIcon);
    p2Taken.push(clickedValue);
    whosTurn = 'X';

    player2CheckWin(p2Taken);

}


function player1CheckWin(p1Taken){

    for(var i=0; i < p1Taken.length; i++) {

        if(p1Taken.length > 2) {

            if(p1Taken[i] == 1 || p1Taken[i] == 2 || p1Taken[i] == 3) { 
    console.log("first");
                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 4 || p1Taken[i] == 5 || p1Taken[i] == 6) {
                    console.log("second");

                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 7 || p1Taken[i] == 8 || p1Taken[i] == 9) {
                    console.log("third");

                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 1 || p1Taken[i] == 4 || p1Taken[i] == 7) {
                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 2 || p1Taken[i] == 5 || p1Taken[i] == 8) {
                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 3 || p1Taken[i] == 6 || p1Taken[i] == 9) {
                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 1 || p1Taken[i] == 5 || p1Taken[i] == 9){
                    message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else if(p1Taken[i] == 3 || p1Taken[i] == 5 || p1Taken[i] == 7) {
                message.innerHTML = "X Won!";
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function player2CheckWin(p2Taken){

    for(var j=0; j < p2Taken.length; j++) {

        if(p2Taken.length > 2) {

            if(p2Taken[j] == 1 || p2Taken[j] == 2 || p2Taken[j] == 3) {
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 4 || p2Taken[j] == 5 || p2Taken[j] == 6) {
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 7 || p2Taken[j] == 8 || p2Taken[j] == 9) {
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 1 || p2Taken[j] == 4 || p2Taken[j] == 7) {
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 2 || p2Taken[j] == 5 || p2Taken[j] == 8) {
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 3 || p2Taken[j] == 6 || p2Taken[j] == 9) {
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 1 || p2Taken[j] == 5 || p2Taken[j] == 9){
                    message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else if(p2Taken[j] == 3 || p2Taken[j] == 5 || p2Taken[j] == 7) {
                message.innerHTML = "O Won!";
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test here? Anyway what's happening is that if the first condition in any of your test (for example : `p1Taken[i] == 1` is true, then the whole expression will be truthy as it will evaluate as true && 2 && 3 which returns 3

Comment: https://github.com/vasanthk/tic-tac-toe-js

Comment: Great I can’t read any of that lol

Answer (score 0):

I'll just pick one of your predicates:

```
p1Taken[i] == 1 && 2 && 3
```

This is `true` iff all of the following are true:

1. `p1Taken[i]` is similar to `1` (after necessary casting)
2. `2` is `true` (after necessary casting)
3. `3` is `true` (after necessary casting)

So I know that the numbers `2` and `3` are truthy and thus casting to boolean will both be `true`. If you meant to compare `p1Taken[i]` to the 3 numbers you need to do 3 comparisons:

```
p1Taken[i] == 1 || p1Taken[i] == 2 || p1Taken[i] == 3
```

If the number always are integers you can use ranges:

```
p1Taken[i] >= 1 && p1Taken[i] <= 3
```

**EDIT**

The key to making something easy rather than hard is to have a though out data structure that supports the operations you want to do. I would imagine that a board with the indexes representing the positions would be just as easy to update and it will be easy to check if one won. Here is how I would have modelled it:

```js
function getWinner(b) {
  if (b[4] && (
      b[3] == b[4] && b[4] == b[5] ||
      b[0] == b[4] && b[4] == b[8] ||
      b[2] == b[4] && b[4] == b[6] ||
      b[1] == b[4] && b[4] == b[7])) {
    return b[4];
  }
  if (b[0] && (
      b[1] == b[0] && b[0] == b[2] ||
      b[3] == b[0] && b[0] == b[6])) {
    return b[0];
  }
  if (b[8] && (
      b[6] == b[8] && b[8] == b[7] ||
      b[2] == b[8] && b[8] == b[5])) {
    return b[8];
  }
  return false;
}

// tests
const o = 'o';
const x = 'x';
const n = undefined;
const test1 = [
  o, o, x,
  x, o, x,
  o, n, x
];

const test2 = [
  o, x, x,
  x, o, o,
  o, n, x
];

const test3 = [
  o, x, x,
  o, o, o,
  x, n, x
];


console.log(getWinner(test1)); // prints x
console.log(getWinner(test2)); // prints false
console.log(getWinner(test3)); // prints o
```

Comment: Well the numbers correspond with the number for the square that the player clicks. Also that is the other part, checking for a win when there are more than 3 moves...

Comment: @UntouchedDruid4 I think you need to rethink your model. How it is now the `p1Taken` will have indexes from the bord in any order. I think it would be much easier that your model was an array where the index where the indexes of the board and that the values were who had checked it. Then you can check `board[0] && board[0] == board[1] &&  board[1] == board[2]`. Notice I assume the board values are falsy (perhaps undefined) when not checked yet. If that expression is true then `board[0]` has won.

Comment: hhmm.. Interesting I’ll have to think about that one. I’ll update the post so that you can see the previous code.

Comment: @UntouchedDruid4 I've updated with an example. A note on your code is that it's not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). eg. my `getWinner` would replace two of your functions that looks very much the same.

Answer (score -1):

you need to correct your logic of comparison

change this

`p1Taken[i] == 1 && 2 && 3`

to

`p1Taken[i] == 1 && p1Taken[i] == 2 && p1Taken[i] == 3`

similarly for others

`&&` operator expects expressions to be compared, in your case you gave first expression as `p1Taken[i] == 1` which is correct but second & third expression given were '2' & '3' which are truthy values

Now about your logic part, the above code still wont give correct result as you expecting same thing `p1Taken[i]` to be equal to multiple values at same time.

so just a hint, `p1Taken` keep it as array of taken tile nos & use condition as

`p1Taken.includes(1) && p1Taken.includes(2) && p1Taken.includes(3)`

[TicTacToe game](http://www.ashok.im/TicTacToe.html)

Comment: That makes zero sense. It expects `p1Taken[i]` to be equal to three different numbers at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and I console.log it. on the first turn p1Taken[i] is equal to 1 then 1 2 and then 1 2 3 by the third turn. Maybe there is a better way to go about the whole thing idk anymore. I’ve been working on this project on and off for months, I’m just tired of looking at it.

Comment: @UntouchedDruid4 I had developed the game, you may check to get the ideas

Comment: @MátéSafranka updated the answer to address the issue, maybe now if not upvote but atleast downvote can be reverted as I have given answer to OP & also explained why it wont work & what is plausible solution

Comment: @vinayakj Fair enough!

Comment: Blah I don’t use jQuery but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @UntouchedDruid4 try `p1Taken.includes(1) && p1Taken.includes(2) && p1Taken.includes(3)`

Comment: @UntouchedDruid4 and no need to use for loop